# Angular material Datepicker get value on change

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using the new version of angular and angular material. I need to get the value of the `datepicker` at the moment the user change the date to then pass that value to a function and do something.

**datepicker**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="roomsFilter.date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker [(ngModel)]="roomsFilter.date" ngDefaultControl (selectedChanged)="onChange($event)"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and this the function.

```
  public onChange(event: any, newDate: any): void {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    // this.getData(newDate);
  }
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me, [check here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rx5ddns6dWM7CdmqnKWg?p=preview)

Comment: I fixed. The datepicker was missing the event for some reason that still don´t why.

Comment: I assume you just want the value, so you can use `console.log(event)` ? https://plnkr.co/edit/8c21pXDrx7OCq93Gppa0?p=preview

Comment: Don't you already have the value in the ngModel binding for the input field?  I don't think you need the ngModel for the #picker itself.  (btw - I know this is an old post, but just looking for testing my datePicker in jasmine test and ran across this.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry I didn't post the answer before, but I solved the problem with the @AJT_82's comment. Here is the code:

**Component HTML**

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="roomsFilter.date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker [(ngModel)]="roomsFilter.date" ngDefaultControl (selectedChanged)="onDate($event)"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**compoment ts**

```
  public onDate(event): void {
    this.roomsFilter.date = event;
    this.getData(this.roomsFilter.date);
  }
```

Basically, I just passed the `$event` of the `datepicker` to get the value.

Comment: `selectedChanged` seems to be removed in later versions of mat-datepicker

Comment: Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 39):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="expiration1" placeholder="Expiration" [formControl]="expiration" required (dateChange)="EndDateChange($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="expiration1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #expiration1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Please check this demo link So you will get more idea.
[Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqnrqneaamj)

Comment: as of today this is working

Answer (score 17):

According to the official documentation, the MatDatepickerInput has a **dateInput** EventEmitter and it emits the selected date.

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input (dateInput)="OnDateChange($event.value)" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
 [placeholder]="field.label" />
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"> </mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: input tag not closed?

Comment: It's closed on the line below, the "[placeholder]="field.label" " belongs to it

Comment: @JonathP it's closed by the line juste below