# How to get selected value of Material DatePicker from component.ts

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a datepicker in a form of my html file. After submitting the form I need to get the selected value of the datepicker in my component.ts file

in the html file:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" ngModel id ="from" name="from" placeholder="From :"> 
</form>

in the component.ts file:
console.log(f.value.from);
```

I have tried the above code and the value I get is undefined.

Comment: Use <mat-datepicker not input type text and then see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572450/5724889

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular material Datepicker get value on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962322/angular-material-datepicker-get-value-on-change)

Answer (score 0):

Add [(ngModel)]

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="from" id ="from" name="from" placeholder="From:">
```

And in .ts declare

```
public from;
```

then it should be avaliable in onSubmit function

Comment: still getting the value as undefined

Answer (score 0):

See this stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcr7ub

Note the two way binding in the form `[(ngModel)]="date"` links to `date` in `app.component.ts` though you could do this using reactive forms.

*app.component.html*

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="example-container">
  Form
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="date" [matDatepicker]="picker" name="date" placeholder="Choose a date" />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
 </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There are a few tricky things I encountered implementing this:

- Importing everything needed to get the basic example https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples working required a few googles and double checkng the API tab

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
```

The last one being as you have to provide a `DateAdapter` for dealing with dates (the datepicker is agnostic about this).

- Remember to include a theme in `styles.css`, I used:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

So in my example the date is a moment (https://momentjs.com/) object hence the `.format()` in:

```
  onSubmit() {
    console.log((<any>this.date).format());
  }
```